# GEE error: (feature).intersection is not a function

Tags: google-earth-engine, features, intersect

I'm trying to intersect the WCMC WDPA polygons with a self-loaded shapefile polygon asset converted to a feature. However, I got the following error message:

> GEE error: (feature).intersection is not a function

Here is my code:

```
//import assest 
import asset
var polygon: Table projects/ee-username/assets/polygon

var aoi = (polygon)

Map.setCenter(long, lat, zoom);
Map.addLayer(aoi, {}, 'name');

// Subset protected areas to the bounds of the feature
// Clip to the intersection with feature.
var protectedAreas = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons')
  .filter(ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.bounds(aoi.geometry()),
    ee.Filter.neq('PA_DEF', 1),
    ee.Filter.neq('NO_TK_AREA', 0)

   ))
    .map(function(feat){
    return aoi.intersection(feat);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely because `polygon` is a feature collection. You can check this with `print(polygon);`.

If there are multiple features in `polygon` you can use `.union()` to collect them into one MultiPart geometry. If you are expecting only one feature in `polygon` you can omit the `.union()` method from the first line.

```js
// collect features into one multipart geometry
var aoi = polygon.union(1); // 1 is the allowed error margin for the union operation (must be non-zero)

// get the first (and only) feature from the feature collection as a computed object and cast it to an ee.Feature
var aoi = ee.Feature(aoi.first());

// Subset protected areas to the bounds of the feature
// Clip to the intersection with feature.
var protectedAreas = ee.FeatureCollection('WCMC/WDPA/current/polygons')
  .filter(ee.Filter.and(
    ee.Filter.bounds(aoi.geometry()),
    ee.Filter.neq('PA_DEF', 1),
    ee.Filter.neq('NO_TK_AREA', 0)
  ))
    .map(function(feat){
    // get the intersection with the AOI and copy across the properties of the input feature
    return aoi.intersection(feat).copyProperties(feat);
  });
  
print(protectedAreas);
Map.addLayer(polygon, {color: '#EFEFEF'});
Map.addLayer(protectedAreas, {color: '#00AA00'});
```

[image]